# Hiding parentView and subviews rather then the last added subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, model-view-controller, uiview

I have custom parent view, which is a sub class `UIView` with some `UIImageView`'s, `UILabel`'s etc..

I add as a subview screenshot of it.I would like to hide all the subviews and the parent view rather then that screenshot.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Code:

```
self.temp = [self snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
self.temp.frame = self.bounds;
[self addSubview:self.temp];
```

Comment: This is not doable. When you hide the parent view, you hide all subviews too, including the screenshot subview.

Comment: Why would you need to hide all the view's other subviews if the snapshot view is already on top of them? When you add the snapshot view on top, everything else becomes hidden underneath it, so you can change whatever you want without having to hide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the screenshot is one of the subview of your parent view. So hiding the parent view will hide all the subviews including the screenshot.

You can do the following

- Make the screenshot size, bound to the parent and add to top
- Present the screenshot as a popover/modal-view and blur the parent view
- Remove/hide all the subviews from the parent except the screenshot